# Amount to words Odoo qweb report for Purchase Requisition

Tags: numbers, report, odoo, words, qweb

I am trying to achieve amount to words in odoo 10. I am overriding the purchase requisition template. I will share my .py and .xml files please check what am I doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

Step1: Created module with scaffold command.

Step2: model.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from odoo import models, fields, api
from openerp import models, api _
from openerp.tools import amount_to_text_en
from openerp import tools
from openerp.tools.amount_to_text import amount_to_text

 class purchase_agreement_updates(models.Model):
     _name = 'purchase_agreement_updates.purchase_agreement_updates'
     _inherit = 'self.header'

     @api.multi
     def amount_to_text(self, amount, currency='Euro'):
         return amount_to_text(amount, currency)
purchase_agreement_updates()
class purchase_requisition(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.requisition'

     @api.multi
     def amount_to_text(self, amount, currency='Euro'):
         return amount_to_text(amount, currency)
```

templates.xml:

```
        <t t-name="purchase_requisition.report_purchaserequisitions">
            <t t-call="report.html_container">
                <t t-foreach="docs" t-as="o">
                    <!--<t t-call="report.external_layout">-->
                        <div class="header">


                              <div style="float:left;width:100px;"></div>
                              <div style="margin:0 auto;width:100%;">
                                  <h3 style="text-align:center;text-decoration: underline;margin-top:50px;">PURCHASE REQUISITION</h3></div>
                              <div style="float:right;width:100px;">
                                  <img t-if="res_company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' %res_company.logo" height="120px" width="100px"/></div>

                            <!--<t t-esc="o.name"/>-->
                        </div>
.
.
.
.
.
.
               <tr t-foreach="o.line_ids" t-as="line_ids">
                                    <t t-set="total_value" t-value="total_value+line_ids.product_qty * line_ids.price_unit"/>
                                    <td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;"><span t-esc="line_ids_index+1"/> </td>
                                    <td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;"><span t-field="line_ids.product_id.name"/></td>
                                    <td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;"><span t-field="line_ids.product_qty"/> </td>
                                    <td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;"><span t-field="line_ids.price_unit"/> </td>
                                    <td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;"><span t-esc="line_ids.product_qty * line_ids.price_unit"/> </td></tr>

                                <tr><td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;"> </td>
                                    <td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;"> </td>
                                    <td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;"> </td>
                                    <td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;">Total </td>
                                    <td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;"> <t t-esc="total_value"/></td></tr>


                                <tr><td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;" colspan="5"><span style="font-weight:bold;">TOTAL PURCHASE:</span> <t t-esc="total_value"/> </td></tr>
                                <tr><td style="border:1px solid #000;padding-left:5px;height:25px;" colspan="5"><span style="font-weight:bold;">TOTAL PURCHASE IN WORDS:</span> <span t-esc="o.amount_to_text(total_value, 'Aed')"/>
                                        <!--<span t-esc="o.amount_to_text('2000', o.currency_id)"/>-->  </td></tr>
```

Error:
Error to render compiling AST
AttributeError: 'purchase.requisition' object has no attribute 'amount_to_text'
Template: 844
Path: /templates/t/t/t/t/div[2]/table[2]/tr[5]/td/span[2]
Node:

Comment: Can you show the report action ?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do any kind of override. Each currency record has this function builtin. If you have multi-currency setup then the order_id of `purchase.requisition` or the company or user should have the reference to currency. Decide which currency you want to use Or you can get the default currency id in qweb and call `currency_id.amount_to_text(o.amount_total)`. Here `currency_id` is the reference to currency object.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is understanding what model is represented by your line_ids.

Your report captures the object(s) it is representing as an object "o" for each object in the parameter "docs" which is passed to the report rendering function.

```
t-foreach="docs" t-as="o"
```

The report is now busy rendering as per your xml for the object "o" and is then iterating over each of the line_ids found within the object "o".

```
t-foreach="o.line_ids" t-as="line_ids"
```

I did not see what model each "line_ids" corresponded to however that model must have the function

```
def amount_to_text()
```

My suspicion is that your function is not in the proper model and if you want to execute the function you must move it to the correct model.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Phillip thank you very much for your detailed reply.

The solution worked for me is like this and as I mentioned in my question I am using odoo 10.

Models.py :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import models, fields, api
import num2words

class purchase_requisition(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.requisition'

    def conv(self, val):
        return num2words.num2words(val)
```

templates.xml :

```
<span t-esc="o.conv(total_value)" style="text-transform:uppercase;"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from odoo.tools import amount_to_text_en

    amt_in_words = fields.Char(compute='set_amt_in_words')

    def set_amt_in_words(self):
            for each in self:
                amount, currency = each.amount_total, each.currency_id.name
                amount_in_words = amount_to_text_en.amount_to_text(amount, lang='en', currency=currency)
                if currency == 'INR':
                    amount_in_words = str(amount_in_words).replace('INR', 'rupees')
                    amount_in_words = str(amount_in_words).replace('Cents', 'paise')
                    amount_in_words = str(amount_in_words).replace('Cent', 'paise')
                amount_in_words += '\tonly'
                each.amt_in_words = amount_in_words.title()

XML :
<span t-esc="o.amt_in_words"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

@api.multi
    def amount_to_text(self, amount, currency='INR'):
        amount_in_words = amount_to_text_en.amount_to_text(amount, lang='en', currency=currency)
        if currency == 'INR':
            amount_in_words = str(amount_in_words).replace('INR', 'rupees')
            amount_in_words = str(amount_in_words).replace('Cents', 'paise')
            amount_in_words = str(amount_in_words).replace('Cent', 'paise')
        amount_in_words += '\tonly'
        return amount_in_words

```
def get_amount_in_words(self, amount):
    amount_in_words = self.amount_to_text(amount)
    return amount_in_words
```

and the xml -